# EAL rte_service_init failed EAL Initialization error

Tags: dpdk

I am trying to execute the example code in dpdk.I am getting the following error  I have 2 versions of dpdk installed in system Please suggest a solution for the issue.

> Blockquote
> EAL: Detected 8 lcore(s)
> EAL: Detected 1 NUMA nodes
> EAL: Detected shared linkage of DPDK
> EAL: Multi-process socket /run/user/1000/dpdk/rte/mp_socket
> EAL: Selected IOVA mode 'VA'
> EAL: No available 16777216 kB hugepages reported
> EAL: 512 hugepages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs found fore
> EAL: Probing VFIO support...
> EAL: VFIO support initialized
> EAL: Couldn't get fd on hugepage file
> EAL: error allocating rte services array
> EAL: FATAL: rte_service_init() failed
> EAL: rte_service_init() failed
> EAL: Error - exiting with code: 1
> Cause: Error with EAL initialization

Edit:Solves the issue-
echo 512|sudo tee /sys/devices/system/node/node0/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages

Comment: based on the limited information `EAL: No available 16777216 kB huge pages reported EAL: 512 huge pages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs` this looks like more of `sudo issue or huge page not available issue`.  Also please update with `dpdk version, application, cmd lien args, --log-level=8`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[EDIT-1] based on the limited information

```
EAL: No available 16777216 kB huge pages reported 
EAL: 512 huge pages of size 2097152 reserved, but no mounted hugetlbfs
```

this looks like more of

1. sudo issue
2. huge page not available issue.

[ima] Thanks, Vipin. Yes, it was hugepage related issue.

Comment: please accept and upvote to close the question. Editing the answer does not update the status.